# gradle junit and error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, gradle, junit, compiler-errors

I'm attempting to run a simple junit test from gradle on an proof of concept class I've compiled and deployed to aws lambda. The class `Auth.java` takes a POJO with a single property `email`. It compiles fine on it's own and works on aws. However, when I run:

```
gradle build
```

I receive the following error:

```
Auth.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println(payload.email);
symbol:   variable email
location: variable payload of type Object
1 error
:compileJava FAILED
```

If I `System.out.println(payload.email);` from within `TestAuth.java` I can access the object's property no problem. Am I failing to grasp some key java or gradle concept here? I've refactored this things 5 different ways and still, I always receive this cannot find symbol error. Anybody have any ideas? Here's my simplified code.

---

./src/main/java/Auth.java

```
package works.valt.api;

public class Auth {

    public Auth(Object payload) {
        System.out.println(payload.email);
    }

}
```

./src/test/java/TestAuth.java

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Before;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import works.valt.api.Auth;

public class TestAuth {

    public class Payload {
      public String email = "test@testing.com";
    }

    private Payload payload;

    // create payload
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
      this.payload = new Payload();
    }    

   @Test
   public void testResponse() {
      Auth response = new Auth(this.payload);
   }
```

}

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}

task buildZip(type: Zip) {
    from compileJava
    from processResources              
    into('lib') {
        from configurations.runtime
    }           
}

build.dependsOn buildZip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructor of `Auth` is having a param of type Object. And `Object` class doesn't have variable called `email`. Change the parameter type to `Payload`

Comment: hold on, just tried to fix this....I'm passing an instance of Payload to the constructor. The constructor accepts Object, Payload is an Object...so why are the properties getting dropped?

Comment: Because compiler will try to find the `email` variable in `Object` which is not there.

Answer (score 1):

This is the constructor of `Auth`

```
public Auth(Object payload) {
    System.out.println(payload.email);
}
```

The payload parameter has type `Object`, so the field `email` is not found the in the Object class definition, and that's what the compiler is complaining about:

> ```
> Auth.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
> System.out.println(payload.email);
> symbol:   variable email
> location:
> variable payload of type Object
> ```

You either change the parameter type to `Payload` or you cast the reference inside the constructor and loose some compile-time type safety

Comment: Can you give me an example of what this would look like?

Comment: Put the Payload definition in its own class in the api package, and then replace Obejct with Payload in the constructor of Auth

Comment: Can you give me an example of casting the reference? I'm having a hard time figuring out what you mean by that. I need to keep the Object generic as I don't know for sure what the payload will look like. The payload is a JSON object that is being auto-serialized by AWS Lambda. Auto-serialized into an object, that is. If it has to be a hardened structure, then I might ditch the java route all together.

Comment: This is the cast operator at work `(Payload) objectRef` - however you should really use a `Map` or a `JsonObject`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is payload is an Object and not Payload

You will have to actually say that it's a Payload in order to access that property:

```
package works.valt.api;

public class Auth {

    public Auth(TestAuth.Payload payload) {
        System.out.println(payload.email);
    }

}
```